# Chain multiple chflags in bash

Tags: linux, macos, bash, shell, terminal

Is it possible to use more than one `chflags` within the same command in `bash`?

```
$ ls -lO
total 2456
-rw-r--r--@ 1 Ned  staff  hidden         1236497 Jul 14 23:52 chart.png
-rw-r--r--@ 1 Ned  staff  schg,hidden       9056 Jul 14 23:52 data.db
-rw-r--r--@ 1 Ned  staff  hidden              39 Jul 28 02:11 info.txt
-rw-r--r--@ 1 Ned  staff  hidden            1681 Jul 17 14:06 notes.md
```

Running the following command seems to have no effect:

```
$ sudo find . -type f \( -flags schg -flags hidden \) -exec -R chflags nohidden -exec -R chflags noschg {} \;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you just looking for this:

```
chflags nohidden,noschg <file>
```

?

Well, that's the *form* of the command. You list the flag changes you want separated by commas.

According to the documentation, you can't remove `schg` in a normal boot. Supposedly, `schg` can only be removed in single-user mode. However, it seems to work fine in practice.

Comment: Thanks, I tried `sudo chflags -R nohidden,noschg *` on osx and it worked. I'm not sure what `single-user mode` is - what is that? and should I report this behavior to apple? it seems like that shouldn't be possible.

Comment: Single-user mode is basically booting the OS to a command-line shell. If you're able to remove `schg` without booting to single-user mode, then at the very least the man pages are wrong. Filing a bug report with Apple would be appropriate. Are you sure it worked? That is, did it really remove `schg` from the files or were you assuming it did because `chflags` didn't report any errors?

Comment: well, i think so...  `ls -lO` shows `-` for flags, so i'm assuming they did get removed. If you're on osx also try it yourself - i'm curious if the behavior is the same for you.